# Angularjs escape json with hypen or dash in ngSrc

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to render an image from json url with dashes. I tried the bracket notation but it is not working:

```
<img ng-src="{{image.['small-size'].url || image.thumb}}">
```

Using single quotes my angular view becomes blank while double-quotes show no image though it exists.

Comment: The bracket notation does not work like this, instead use `image['small-size']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove dot

```
<img ng-src="{{image['small-size'].url || image.thumb}}">
```

Comment: Thank you, my usage was erroneous.